# I want to design this complex table structure in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tabular

I want to design this complex table structure in bootstrap.

In this image there is dashed vertical line which comes along display button (I don't want this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want we do the job for you ? or just a link to help ? ^^

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Since you are new here please understand. SO is a platform to clear doubts and solve problems in an **already implemented systems**. It is not a place where you can expect a complete from the scratch solution like a freelancing platform.

Comment: Thnk u guys for reply.. i want entire solution .. should i use colspan rowspan in it?

Comment: no worries ... done with that part ... giving a solution is more important than asking a question or giving rubbish suggestions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you can easily design by using simple table, thead, tr,th,tbody

Comment: yes done with rowspan and colspan ... cheers mate